# How do I get my distro update dialog back?

Tags: upgrade, synaptic, do-release-upgrade

At some point in the last few weeks I got a notice about upgrading to 15.10, and dismissed it. I figured it would come back, but it hasn't. How do I reset my notifications so that it will come back and I can update?

I know I can do a command line `dist-upgrade`, but I'd like to see the dialog again.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` won't upgrade the Ubuntu release, `do-release-upgrade` will do that..

Comment: all the more reason to get the dialog back...

Comment: Can't you do `do-release-upgrade` then? to get the desktop notification, check the `Software & Updates` (search in dash), then check `updates` tab and then look for `notify me of a new Ubuntu version option`..i am on 14.04..15.04 should have something similar..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the useful command line suggestions in the comments not withstanding, I still wanted this.

As it turns out, in the Software Updater (not Synaptic) settings, under Updates, there's an pulldown for "Notify my of a new Ubuntu version:" -- if you change it to "Never," quit the updater, re-open the updater and change it back to "For any new version" you'll definitely see the dialog.

Which is what I wanted.